# Conversion of Boolean value into String value in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a boolean field in a MySQL database.  When displaying the selected rows from the DB on the datagrid in C#, I want this field to be displayed as "true" or "false".

Can somebody help me out in telling how can I do it?

Comment: What technology? Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET?

Answer (score 7):

Typically, this will happen automatically.  It depends on how you're pulling the Boolean across into C#, but it will normally get treated as a `bool`, which in turn will turn into "True" or "False" when it's ToString() method is called.

Comment: More specifically, "True" or "False" (note the capitalization)

Answer (score 4):

```
String.Format("The boolean value is {0}", boolValue ? "true" : "false");
```

You could wrap the ternary statement in some ToFriendlyString() extension method. This will allow you to say ANYTHING; true/false, yes/no, up/down, black/white, whatever the Boolean value really represents in your model.

`Boolean.ToString()` returns a capitalized "True" or "False"; you can format that as necessary using `ToLower()`.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers will work for you in C#, however if you can do it at the Database level:

```
CASE WHEN FIELD_NAME 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS [FIELD NAME]
```

This would require you to change the return type to a string/varchar.